# CSS - Calc alternative

Tags: css, css-selectors, width

I have developed code which works perfectly fine, but as I have used `calc` function, some browsers do not support it. I have no clue of using alternative to it.

I have seen some answers and also tried using relative,absolute positions. However, none of them worked for my scenario.

My code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <img height="35" width="35" class="img left" />
    <div class="title left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultrices orci mauris, sit amet luctus enim sodales id.</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="type"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultrices orci mauris.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.title{width:calc(100% - 50px);} // 35px of image + 5px margin + 10px of icon
```

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wLgh/) here.

PS: I want CSS only solution. Right now, as I dont have any solution I am using javascript to adjust width.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this you want **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wLgh/2/)**

```
.title {
    margin:0 10px 0 40px;
}
```

Comment: ya even i got surprised when you asked this :D